# Label inside TableCell not resizing

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, constraints, autolayout

I've added a label inside a tableviewcell (Prototype cell) and using storyboard I've applied the following constraints on the label:

- 50 leading margin
- 50 trailing margin
- 20 top margin
- 20 bottom margin

In landscape mode(iPad), the label appears correctly.

In portrait mode my label does not resize like I would expect it to do and as you can see below the label width is longer than the screen size.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you also applied the constraints to the tableview too? The current constraints may be doing exactly what they should in relation to the tableviewcell, though if you could check first the tableview isn't stretching off screen. NSLog the frame to check this

Comment: tableviewcell width and height stays at 600x600 starting with XCode 6 irrespective of whether the screen on ipad is landscape or portrait. What constraints should i apply on the tableview though?

Comment: You mention iPad, though the simulator screenshot you're showing is for the iPhone? iPhone's pixel width is only 320, which will be why it's showing off screen here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out :)

Here's the problem with tableviews in general.

When you drag a tableview onto a View it resizes itself quickly in storyboard to fill the view container completely. So, like most people there didn't seem to be an easy way to apply the constraints on the tableview.

So, this time I dragged the tableview a bit so that I could see the bounds.

Here's how I was able to see the bounds between the tableview and right margin.

[image]

Here's how I moved the tableview so that I could see some separation between the left margin of the tableview and the containerview.

[image]

Once I was able to see the separation between the tableview and it's containerview I applied the following bounds between them like this:

trailing margin : 1

leading margin : 1

top Space : 1

bottom space : 1

After this point when my view resized from portrait to landscape so did my tableview, and so did my labels.

Programming is cool :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Autosizing and select the right bar. Sorry I can't post an image for more help